# Ubuntu 20.04 installer does not start boot

Tags: boot, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 mate installer both from DVD and Flash Drive.
My Problem is that the installer medium does not start to boot by using either 
of them.
Both medium's installers can boot and start the installation process on other 
systems, so I think the problem may refer to the system hardware I'm using
as the installation platform, as yet it is obeying the minimum system requirements
noted on the web. The fun fact is that LMDE 4 or ubuntu 18.04 installers 
can boot and start running on the same system.
My system config are:
CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E6750  @ 2.66GHz 
Ram : 3 GB 

Having a lot of disk space, I am wondering if I can at all install Ubuntu 20
on this system. Can you please help find out a way to install it if it is possible
for my system.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solve the problem by creating a live USB using `MX Live USB Maker`.
 
I always used to burn the ISO image directly on a DVD or used rufus and such (in wndows)
to create a boot-able drive and it always used to work. 
 
It is good to say the loaded Ubuntu started working fantastically and with no errors when ran 
in `Try Ubuntu` choice offered by installer.